# Transforming .csv Discovery Report into pipe delimited Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting, analytics, data-import, sftp

We would like to export a Marketing Cloud Discovery report. Marketing Cloud only gives you four options for download or SFTP:  .csv, pdf., .xlsx, .xsl . Is there a workaround for transforming a columned report into a pipe-delimited .txt file?

Our aim is trying to export the report, then import that report into a data extension. The only issue is that when we import the .csv, we have to select ',' as a delimiter. This causes an exception, as we have some data that has ',' in the values themselves. This causes an InvalidFieldCount error upon import.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you export a Discover report as a csv file, Discover uses double-quote as the text qualifier. In order to successfully import a file like this to a Data Extension, ensure you check the "Respect double quotes as a text delimiter" box when defining the Import Definition.

[image]

In this way, you'll see data that incorporates commas successfully import into your DE:

[image]